# cannot import name GoogleMaps in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the code below to get the latitude & longitude of an address:

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
gmaps = GoogleMaps(api_key)
address = 'Constitution Ave NW & 10th St NW, Washington, DC'
lat, lng = gmaps.address_to_latlng(address)
print lat, lng
```

but am getting the error below

```
File "C:/Users/Pavan/PycharmProjects/MGCW/latlong6.py", line 1, in <module>
    from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
ImportError: cannot import name GoogleMaps
```

I have seen another question similar to this, but the solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [geopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy) instead, no need for api-key.

From their example:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
print(location.address)
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

prints:

```
Flatiron Building, 175, 5th Avenue, Flatiron, New York, NYC, New York, 10010,  United States of America
(40.7410861, -73.9896297241625)
```

Comment: this code is working fine for single location & when am passing multiple locations am getting all latitudes & longitudes same..

Comment: this seems to work now.. anyhow I need to locate 44,000 locations.. will try to put them in a file & will pass them..

Comment: @PavanChakravarthy I'm not too familiar with the library but they do seem to have nice documentation https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/

Comment: as expected the above code worked fine for few locations & if it couldnt find the coordinates it would fail other locations also..

Comment: @PavanChakravarthy Yes geopy seems to not be able to handle some types of addresses.  Check out my other answer using photon.komoot.de.

Comment: @Scott slightly off topic, but I am wondering if you know of a way to generate lat longs from zip codes? I am having some trouble locating a good solution for python, thank you!

Comment: @Brian I have had to do that before.  You basically need to know the center or some representative lat/lon for the whole zip code.  Different sites have compiled extensive lists in csv format from government data.  Read it in perhaps as a dictionary with key and zip code and value as object/named tuple that contains lat/lon. Top link right now on google is https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666 containing data from 2013.

Comment: @Scott thanks for the reply. The US ones aren't as big of a pain to handle. I am trying to do this across the world for ~1.2 million zip to zip combinations. I am trying to avoid paying for an API. However it doesn't look like any packages accomplish this at scale.

Comment: @Brian Sorry I don't know of any free service with worldwide data.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is the `Client` class not `GoogleMaps`.

If you want to call it `GoogleMaps` import it as follows:

`from googlemaps import Client as GoogleMaps`

Comment: did that & now am getting this error 

File "C:/Users/Pavan/PycharmProjects/MGCW/latlong6.py", line 2, in <module>
    gmaps = GoogleMaps(api_key)
NameError: name 'api_key' is not defined

Comment: @PavanChakravarthy that's because you need an api.  Use geopy instead.

Comment: Did you define the name api_key? It seems that you didn't.

Comment: Check this out for a description of the API key: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python#api-keys

Answer (score 4):

Another option is parsing the json from [photon.komoot.de](http://photon.komoot.de/).  Example:

```
import requests, json

url = 'http://photon.komoot.de/api/?q='
addresses = ['175 5th Avenue NYC', 'Constitution Ave NW & 10th St NW, Washington, DC']

for address in addresses:
    resp = requests.get(url=url+address)
    data = json.loads(resp.text)
    print data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
```

prints:

```
[-76.1438449, 40.229888]
[-77.046567, 38.8924587]
```

These are given in lon, lat.  The second one is a bit off by about 1 mile. Seems street intersections are difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I could write a code for multiple address but it never worked..
Finally found this website which could generate geocodes in bulk..
I think it may be useful to someone looking for bulk geocodes..
It also has reverse geocoding..

http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/#.VW2KRs-qqkq

Answer (score 2):

Andrzej's answer worked for me!

```
from googlemaps import Client as GoogleMaps
```

Just to add to what he said, you will need to

- Click on the API Library in your Google Cloud Platform console
- Search for "Geolocation API"
- Click on "Enable"

If you create an API key before enabling this, you will also get that error. I had the same issue.

Under the "Credentials" tab, you will then see the option to create or copy your API key.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve the issue by deactivating venv, uninstalling googlemaps, reactivating venv, and re-installing googlemaps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
pip install -U googlemaps
```

use this statement to install and use googlemaps api in Python

Comment: Your answer is not true. The problem is from the package, not the installation!