# Plotting points in google maps using Python

Tags: python, google-maps, pygmaps

I am trying to find a library to use in order to plot some points in a specific google map location. I found `pygmaps` and `gmplot`. When I try to import `gmplot`(it is installed) I got the following error:

```
>import gmplot

Traceback (most recent call last):
                .
                .
from gmplot import GoogleMapPlotter
ImportError: cannot import name 'GoogleMapPlotter'
```

On the other hand trying to install `pygmaps` using pip it seems that it doesnt find the library:

```
>pip install pygmaps

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygmaps( from versions:)
```

I could not find any info about it on the net. Any idea what could be wrong or if there is another library to do my task? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since there are few deprecated Google Maps API like Google Maps Engine and Google Maps Coordinate, you may download the latest client library for Python as given in [API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#top_of_page).

This SO post - [Cannot import name GoogleMaps in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523141/cannot-import-name-googlemaps-in-python) might also help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The version of `gmplot` on pypi didn't get bumped when support for python3+ imports was added, which was the cause for the `ImportError`. If you upgrade the installation, it should work right now with version 1.1.1.